# Composite component with multiple input fields, validation failed in WebSphere 8.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, composite-component

I trying to learn composite component magic by implementing this well know example : [Composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html) Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Now in details. When I try to implement it using WAS 8.0.0.9 with embedded JSF implementation based on Apache MyFaces 2.0 i get the following error:

```
[12/30/14 22:34:00:375 IST] 00000095 BeanValidator W   cannot validate component with empty value: form:inputDate:day
[12/30/14 22:34:00:376 IST] 00000095 BeanValidator W   cannot validate component with empty value: form:inputDate:month
[12/30/14 22:34:00:377 IST] 00000095 BeanValidator W   cannot validate component with empty value: form:inputDate:year
```

When I implemented this example on WildFly 8.2 + Apache MyFaces 2.2 all works like expected.

This is how I'm using this composite component on web page:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <hc:inputDate id="inputDate" value="#{testBean.date}"></hc:inputDate>
    <h:outputText id="outputDate" value="#{testBean.date}"></h:outputText>
    <p:commandButton update="outputDate" process="inputDate outputDate"/>             

</h:form>
```

Everything else just like in @BalusC example, without changes.

What am I doing wrong? Can it be a bug in JSF implementation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, WildFly doesn't use [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org). It uses [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net).

As to your concrete problem, it turns out that in case of `UIInput`, [MyFaces](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/2.2.0/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.processValidators%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) first processes the validation phase on the component's children and then finally the component itself, while [Mojarra](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.processValidators%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) does exactly the other way round. Evidence can be found in the provided source code (click the links to see it).

In case of successful validation, the `UIInput` component's submitted value is always set to `null`. In case of MyFaces, the `getSubmittedValue()` method in backing component, which is only invoked *after* all of its children have been processed,

```
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    return day.getSubmittedValue()
        + "-" + month.getSubmittedValue()
        + "-" + year.getSubmittedValue();
}
```

thus always ends up returning `null-null-null`, causing a conversion error in `getConvertedValue()`, because it's not parseable as `dd-MM-yyyy`.

In order to solve this problem, and keep it compatible between Mojarra and MyFaces, better check beforehand if the local value is set or not (i.e. the component was already successfully validated), and then use either `getSubmittedValue()` or `getValue()` accordingly.

```
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    return (day.isLocalValueSet() ? day.getValue() : day.getSubmittedValue())
        + "-" + (month.isLocalValueSet() ? month.getValue() : month.getSubmittedValue())
        + "-" + (year.isLocalValueSet() ? year.getValue() : year.getSubmittedValue());
}
```

The blog article has been updated to take this into account.

Comment: It doesn't work yet, @BalusC. I came only today to work so couldn't check it before that, my apologize. When I use your solution as is, visually component works as should but continue throw in console message: `cannot validate component with empty value: form:inputDate:day`. I've tried to add to every 'h:selectOneMenu', 'value="#{cc.dayValue}"' and define in backing component Integer dayValue. I done same for month and year accordingly. Now it doesn't throw an exception when I perform submit. But when I change day or month value it throw `NullPointerException` at `(Integer) year.getValue()`

Comment: inside `updateDaysIfNecessary`. Hmm... I guess that I need to perform check `year.isLocalValueSet()` here too before I trying to get an value from here. Will try to implement it and will write here.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. First I was need to add: `execute="day month year"` in `h:selectOneMenu`for month and year, otherwise it didn't get submitted value and always returned. And In update days if necessary I added the following code: `Integer monthSelected = month.isLocalValueSet() ? (Integer)month.getSubmittedValue()-1 : (Integer)month.getValue()-1;
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthSelected);`  This is my working code, which works without any exceptions: http://pastebin.com/irdQunia - xhtml page and http://pastebin.com/Vj83n0HN - backing bean